# Kill a maven java process gracefully

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am using maven to run a java process as a server. exec-maven-plugin is used to run the main java class. I use a bat file to start it like:

```
call mvn exec:java -Dexec.args="xxxxx"
```

I want to kill the process when I want restart this process. So how can I tell maven to kill the existing running process? Can I pass a process id (or name) when I start the maven process? So then I know which process to kill when I want to re-run the same java application. Basically I want to use a single bat file to start and kill the same process gracefully with out trying to figure out the process id.

Comment: Why do you use Maven for this?

Comment: I use maven to run the project. But to kill the process, it doesn't have to be maven. I just want to put all these commands in a .bat file to run it as a script

Comment: I mean: Why don't you just run java? What does Maven help you here?

Comment: Ok, let's assume that I run java command. Then what is the answer for my question?

Comment: I guess you need to write a new question for that.

Comment: lol. This conversation didn't help me at all :-)

Comment: I am sorry, but if you write a question with three "maven" tags, and your question seems to be about running and killing java processes, it is very unlikely that you get a sensible answer because the Java process experts just won't notice it.

Comment: If I can assign a process id or process name, when I am starting the main java program via exec-maven-plugin, then I can kill that process later when ever I want, via kill command

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: It is a question. How to get the process id if I am using the exec-maven-plugin? I saw someone mentioned via ant-plugin. I might try that if there is no way to do this via exec-maven-plugin